# Eclipse C++1y (-std=c++1y) vs -std=c++11

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I'm working with eclipse and I can choose the language standard and/or other dialect flags. When I want to work with the latest language standard, do I need to declare as shown in the image or leave the language standard blank  and just define c++11, or the other way around, just define the language standard c++1y and leave the flags empty?

[image]

Comment: language flags depend on your compiler. So find out your compiler version - then go to its documentation and find which -std values are supportd by this version and decide how you'll be able to select specific standard

Comment: C++11 isn't exactly the latest standard, so I wouldn't select that.

Comment: Eclipse isn't a compiler. What does your compiler support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) `-std=c++1y` is just a deprecated alias to `-std=c++14`, not to `-std=c++11`. Even though Eclipse offered a proper alternative option `-std=c++0x`, it is also deprecated, so you better leave language standard blank and set `-std=c++11` among flags.